# how to change form field from submit controller

Tags: forms, symfony

i try to change value of a field form in my controller , in submit button.

I try this :

```
   if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
           if($form->get('add_proprietario')->isClicked()){
    $form->get('idProprietario')->setData($proprietario->getId());
}
}
```

but return error

```
   You cannot change the data of a submitted form.
```

How i can do it??

Comment: hmm.. form events?

Comment: as @ArtOsi suggested, form events are also a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Change it directly on Entity.

If you have something like this:

```
$entity = new Entity();
$form = $this->createForm(EntityType::class, $entity);

$form->handleRequest($request);

if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
   if ($form->get('add_proprietario')->isClicked()) {
       $entity->setProprietario($proprietario->getId())
   }
}
```